# Swift - A strange UIView instant covering over the whole top most ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I just updated my Xcode to 8.2.1 and migrated my swift codes from 2.2 to 3.0.

After that, I ran into a situation that my top-most view controller was covered by a view ([for more detail, please click to see the screenshot of Xcode debug hierarchy view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybpCi.png)), which never appeared when swift 2.2 was used.  The top most VC is a DrawerController from https://cocoapods.org/pods/DrawerController, and is updated to the last version.

Because every touch event was received by the strange view, my app can't
work normally.

Is there any potential reason to make the view there?
Or is there any way to find out where the view come from?

If more information is needed, please let me know. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can try loop through your view.subViews to remove that top view, maybe its bug from the lib

Comment: @Tj3n But according to the hierarchy screenshot, the top view is at the level above the level of the DrawerController rather than below that of the DrawerController.  I have no idea about how to get the superview of the  top view.

Answer (score 0):

For lack of  reputation, I can't comment.

Have you ever tried to delete this "strange view"? Or just move it on top the UIView that contains your drawer?

Comment: How to get the reference of the strange view?  I guess I need it's reference to delete, or if there is some way to delete it please let me know.

Comment: I see, so you can't delete it directly on storyboard?

Comment: The strange view is not added from storyboard.  The screenshot in my post is taken from the left side of the debug hierarchy window, but not the storyboard window.

Comment: Oh! I thought it was taken from storyboard, my bad. Hmm, can you try this one out?

    `childView.superview.bringSubview(toFront: childView)`

childView would be the UIView that contains your Drawer.

Comment: You can add an IBOutlet so you get a reference for UIView that contains your Drawer.

Comment: The DrawerController is presented by the rootViewController of my app.  Actually I did not layout the DrawerController in the UIView (so I can't add an IBOutlet to the UIView), and the UIView just appears in the debug hierarchy view like it is with the DrawerController contained in it.

Comment: Can you try if this is possible? self.view.bringSubview(toFront: Drawer)

Comment: Thank you Cuevas!  After a lot of try and error, finally solved this problem by make a main queue.  I will share the detail ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem.

In my original codes, I subclassed DrawerController (say, MyDrawerController) and assigned the property centerViewController (the main page shown to the user in DrawerController) in the overrided viewDidLoad() in MyDrawerController.  As a result, I ran into the trouble as described in my question above.

What I do to resolve the problem is make a main queue and move the codes which assigning the property centerViewController to the block of the main queue. (Codes of "BEFORE" and "AFTER" like bellow.)

Then, the problem was solved.

Don't know why the "BEFORE" codes worked fine in Swift 2.2 but failed in Swift 3.3.  Could anyone tell the difference?

Thanks for your helping.

BEFORE:

```
class MyDrawerController: DrawerController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {  
        self.centerViewController = aViewControllerInstant 
    } 

}
```

AFTER:

```
class MyDrawerController: DrawerController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {  

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.centerViewController = aViewControllerInstant 
        }

    } 

}
```